# Handling Anonymous IEnumerable Type in MediaTypeFormatter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

I followed this [great example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) and was able to implement my Custom Media Type Formatter. It works great for known types such as Product, Item, Address etc. However if I have anonymous JSON object (below), which I would like to download as CSV then it fails at `Type itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];` complaining

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Any help is appreciated.

```
var _list = _dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new
{
  LkpColCode = r.Field<string>("lkp_column_code"),
  LkpColName = r.Field<string>("Description")
});

return _list;

/* [{"lkpColCode":"BUS","lkpColName":"Bus"},{"lkpColCode":"COM","lkpColName":"Community Bus"},
    {lkpColCode":"STC","lkpColName":"Streetcar"},{"lkpColCode":"SUB","lkpColName":"Subway"},
    {"lkpColCode":"TRC","lkpColName":"Trolley Coach"}]*/
```

**EDIT: Complete working code below that can handle any Type except Anonymous**

```
public class CSVFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
    {
        private string FileName { get; set; }

        public CSVFormatter()
        {
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv"));

            SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false));
            SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
        }

        public CSVFormatter(MediaTypeMapping mediaTypeMapping)
            : this()
        {
            MediaTypeMappings.Add(mediaTypeMapping);

            SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false));
            SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
        }

        public CSVFormatter(IEnumerable<MediaTypeMapping> mediaTypeMappings)
            : this()
        {
            foreach (var mediaTypeMapping in mediaTypeMappings)
            {
                MediaTypeMappings.Add(mediaTypeMapping);
            }

            SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false));
            SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
        }

        public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(Type type, HttpContentHeaders headers, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
        {
            base.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType);
            headers.Add("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", FileName));
        }

        public override MediaTypeFormatter GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
        {
             //Usuage: In Controller Action:
            //if (!Request.Properties.ContainsKey("filename"))
            //Request.Properties.Add("filename", String.Format("SomeFileName_{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss")));

            if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("filename"))
            {
                FileName = request.Properties["filename"] as string;
            }
            else if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileName = request.GetQueryString("filename")))
            {
                FileName = FileName.CustomCompare(".csv") ? FileName : FileName + ".csv";
            }
            else
            {
                FileName = String.Format("Data-{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"));
            }

            return this;
        }

        public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            if (type == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

            return isTypeOfIEnumerable(type);
        }

        private bool isTypeOfIEnumerable(Type type)
        {
            foreach (Type interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
            {
                if (interfaceType == typeof(IEnumerable))
                { return true; }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
        {
            writeStream(type, value, stream, content);
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
            tcs.SetResult(0);
            return tcs.Task;
        }

        private void writeStream(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContent content)
        {
            //NOTE: We have check the type inside CanWriteType method. If request comes this far, the type is IEnumerable. We are safe. However it fails for Anonymous and errors out.

            Encoding effectiveEncoding = SelectCharacterEncoding(content.Headers);
            Type itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, effectiveEncoding))
            {
                //Write out columns
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join<string>(",", itemType.GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name)));

                foreach (var obj in (IEnumerable<object>)value)
                {
                    var vals = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Select(pi => new { Value = pi.GetValue(obj, null) });
                    string _valueLine = string.Empty;

                    foreach (var val in vals)
                    {
                        var columnValue = Escape(val.Value);
                        _valueLine = string.Concat(_valueLine, columnValue, ",");
                    }

                    _valueLine = _valueLine.Substring(0, _valueLine.Length - 1);
                    writer.WriteLine(_valueLine);
                }
            }
        }

        #region Escape Characters
        static char[] _specialChars = new char[] { ',', '\n', '\r', '"' };

        private string Escape(object o)
        {
            if (o == null)
                return String.Empty;

            string field = o.ToString();

            // Delimit the entire field with quotes and replace embedded quotes with "".
            if (field.IndexOfAny(_specialChars) != -1)
                return String.Format("\"{0}\"", field.Replace("\"", "\"\""));
            else return field;

            //Quote forcefully
            //return String.Format("\"{0}\"", field.Replace("\"", "\"\""));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: _then it fails._ How? Please be more specific.

Comment: @MartinLiversage please see the updated code. I am trying to handle Anonymous type within this Media Formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it's just an anonymous type, JSON has nothing to do with this.

Secondly the example that you are working from uses Types to work out if it can or cannot format the data. If you are using an anonymous type then it cannot work as it is.

Easiest route would be to create a new class

```
public class Thing
{
    public string LkpColCode {get;set;}
    public string LkpColName {get;set;}
}
```

And then from the example change `Product` to `Thing` (or whatever you call it) and then change this code

```
private void WriteItem(Thing thing, StreamWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteLine("{0},{1}", Escape(thing.LkpColCode), Escape(thing.LkpColName));
}
```

Give that a go and see where it takes you. If you need more help you'll probably want to update your question with more code.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question that my code can handle known type so this solution doesn't exactly help. I specifically want to know is there a way to handle Anonymous type as sometimes you need to send data in an Anonymous object. Please see updated question.